# getting NaN in D3 js Y function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

below code gives me Nan while I am trying to plot a graph using D3js

```
g.selectAll(".bar")
.data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
.attr("class", "bar")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.key); })
.attr("y", function(d) { return y(parseInt(d.value/10000)); })
.attr("width", x.bandwidth())
.attr("height", function(d) { console.log(d); return height - y(parseInt(d.value)); });
```

as per detailed stack trace

```
y(parseInt(d.value))
```

is throwing me a NaN despie the fact that I am passing an Integer stored in d.value.

any suggestions.

Comment: `return x(d.key)` is in d3v4. Make sure you're using the correct script version.

Comment: Can you post more context? What are the `x` and `y` functions? (I'm not a D3 expert and I can't see any D3 documentation listing what contexts they're available in).

Comment: Also, please post the actual stack-trace, not just the call-site.

Comment: @Could you further elaborate on that? How is that specific to v4?

Comment: i am using d3v4. Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute y="NaN"(anonymous function) @ d3.v4.min.js:3

Comment: @RajeevAkotkar did you end up fixing the issue?